# How to extract a specific key from json in AWS Lambda?

Tags: json, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I am working with AWS Lambda and have the following output:

The output is:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "my_header": "my_value"
  },
  "body": [
    {
      "_index": "xyz",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "1",
      "_score": 2.6251922,
      "_source": {
        "ColW": "Ram",
        "ColX": "Shyam",
        "ColY": 123,
        "ColZ": "James"
      }
    }]
```

However, I just want to return ColW, ColX, ColY in the body. I tried out *search[0]['_source']['ColX']* to print the column X but it's giving me error. Could you please help me out?

Comment: You skipped one level. Try `search['body'][0]['_source']['ColX']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you skipped one level, the **body** node of the output that you have.

So in order to return the fields that you need you should do something like this (*it depends on how do you want to format the output*) deleting only the node that you dont want:

```
filter_output = search['body'][0]['_source']
del filter_output['ColZ']
return filter_output
```

Or if you wanna go in a more detailed way (because you don't know if there will be more nodes to delete) you can do something like this:

```
filter_output = {'ColW':search['body'][0]['_source']['ColW'],
                 'ColX':search['body'][0]['_source']['ColX'],
                 'ColY':search['body'][0]['_source']['ColY']}
return filter_output
```

In this case i created a new dict to return only the required nodes.

Answer (score 0):

- You can delete the keys which you don't want

```
result = your_output_dictionary
del result['body'][0]['_index'] # like this delete keys you don't want
print(required_output)
```